# Query for streaming dataset in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, spark-structured-streaming

I have a **streaming** Dataset with columns: bag_id, ball_color. I want to find the most popular color for each bag. So, I tried:

```
dataset.groupBy("bag_id", "color") # 1st aggregation
       .agg(count("color").as("color_count"))
       .groupBy("bag_id") # 2nd aggregation
       .agg(max("color_count"))
```

But I had an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Multiple streaming aggregations are not supported with streaming
>   DataFrames/Datasets;;

Can I create right query with only one aggregation function?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @ggeop Thank you for helping. I resolved my issue with only one aggregation with function sum

Comment: perfect, nice news :-) I had the same issue, but I didn't have this flexibility to use one aggregation, so I used `foreachBatch()` method.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open Jira addressing this issue [Spark-26655](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26655), as of now we can't run multiple aggregations on the Streaming data.

One workaround would be Performing **`one aggregation`** and saving back to Kafka..etc and again read from kafka to perform another aggregation.

**`(or)`**

We can run only one aggregation on the streaming data and saving it to HDFS/Hive/HBase and fetch to perform additional aggregations(this would be seperate job)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Spark 2.4.4 (latest for now) is NOT support yet Multiple streaming aggregations. But, as a workaround you can use the `.foreachBatch()` [method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch):

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
  df.groupBy("bag_id","color")
  .agg(count("color").as("color_count"))
  .groupBy("bag_id").agg(max("color_count"))
  .show() # .show() is a dummy action

streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

In `.foreachBatch()` the df is not a streaming df, so you can do everything you want.